# Facebook API in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript

Basically I am trying to connect to Facebook using actionscript 3.0. If I were to run the application in Facebook, and it is connected to Facebook, the stamp image would be added to the screen. The codes below are the functions used:

```
private var facebookAppID:String = "myappID";
private var fbLoggedIn:Boolean = false;

public function tryout() {

Facebook.init(facebookAppID, onInit);

FBConnect();

}

protected function onInit(result:Object, fail:Object):void {
    if (result) { //already logged in because of existing session
        fbLoggedIn = true;
    } else {
        fbLoggedIn = false;
    }
}

public function FBConnect():void {
    trace("in FBConnect");
    if (fbLoggedIn)
    {
            showFbForm();
            trace("success logged in");
    }
    else
    { // attempt to request for login
        var opts:Object = {scope:"publish_stream, email"};
        Facebook.login(onLogin, opts);
        trace("failed logged in");
    }
}

protected function onLogin(result:Object, fail:Object):void {
    trace("in onLogin");
    if (result) { //successfully logged in
        fbLoggedIn = true;
        showFbForm();
    } else {
        fbLoggedIn = false;
        return;
    }
}

protected function showFbForm():void {
    addChild(stamp1);
    stamp1.x = 0;
    stamp1.y = 0;
    trace("in showFBForm()");
}
```

The stamp1 should be displayed on the stage. However, nothing is displayed at all. I have been trying and researched but it still does not display.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're hiding your app ID or you just filled in `MyAppID` as your appID,
but if it's the second then it won't work because that appID does not exist. You need to find your appID in your facebook dashboard.

Since your code can't connect to the appID, it won't show any content because the content of "myAppID" is null.